# Does data reset wipe batterystatus.bin?

Tags: root-access, custom-roms, battery, battery-history

Does data reset delete `batterystats.bin`?

Location of `batterystats.bin` file is `/data/system/batterystats.bin`.

***Note:*** NVRAM also remains in data partition but data reset does not wipe IMEI.

Can I calibrate the battery without rooting the new custom ROM?

Comment: What is a "data reset"? And what has the `batterystats.bin` to do with battery calibration (it only holds usage stats of apps)? To calibrate your battery, simply run it down to below 20% (but not below 5% if it can be avoided), and then charge it up to 100% in a single run without disconnect. Done.

Answer (score 1):

If you wipe data/factory reset in ClockWorkMod or TWRP recovery, then it should remove it. The stock recovery **probably** will wipe it.

**In general**, to access recovery, turn off your phone and pull the battery (certain phones have a mode where they "hibernate" instead of powering off...)

Hold the volume up button and then hold the power button. When the phone vibrates release the power button but keep holding volume up.

Note: Factory resetting in Android may **not** remove this file. [A research project by Cambridge University](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/55837/20150527/androids-factory-reset-does-not-wipe-your-data-heres-the-solution.htm) showed that there is a security flaw in some Android devices where not all the files are wiped...

This is because the recovery formats the data partition, so it will certainly be deleted.